# RHEL 8.2 podman rootless container network bottleneck at 20Mbits/s

Tags: redhat, python, podman

When I run container by podman 1.6.4 on RHEL8.2 (fresh install) with rootless user.
The maximum upload speed per container will be around 22Mbits/s (with 1Gbits/s network)
After start a second process, total network usage will go up to ~45Mbits/s (~ 23Mbits/s per container)
Then start a third process, total network usage will go up to ~74Mbits/s (~ 23Mbits/s per container)
So, I suspect that network speed limitation might be something from podman container.
Does anyone know how to disable upload speed limit for rootless container in RHEL?

====
Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir boto3

COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["python","upload.py"]
```

upload.py will upload a million of files with multithread to AWS S3.

#1
After investigate, I found similar bug here
Rootless network serious bandwidth reduction? #8834
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8834
After change mtu to 1500 or 9000, upload speed still limit at ~23Mbits/s.
I also try to change net work to host with `--network=host` but the speed's not change.
So, it might not be related with these bug report.

#2
Try to run program without podman container on other machine (original machine allow to run only podman container), it can use maximum speed. The problem should be from podman or RHEL.

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo plotnetcfg` when you run from the host machine? (not from podman container)